# mac mysqldb "import MySQLdb",but show "ImportError"

Tags: python, mysql-python

mac 10.11osx，and mysql5.5 python 2.7(system) mysqldb1.2.5,but when i do "import MySQLdb",it wrong----------

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 19:19:21) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import MySQLdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4-py2.7-macosx-10.11-intel.egg/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    import _mysql
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4-py2.7-macosx-10.11-intel.egg/_mysql.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4-py2.7-macosx-10.11-intel.egg/_mysql.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

could someone tell me why?

Comment: You somehow installed the wrong package.

Comment: could you tell me which package may wrong?

Comment: The MySQL-python package. It says there, right in the error message.

Comment: thanks，may i  need to think a moment